# Does the new code of conduct exclude certain "erotica" questions?

Tags: discussion

I just noticed that there was a [featured Stack Exchange Meta "question"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240594/proposed-new-code-of-conduct-for-all-stack-exchange-sites) about the [new code of conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/code-of-conduct) (which was intended to be a clarification of the intention behind the earlier rules). This includes the statement "Sexually suggestive language, imagery, and attention are not appropriate for any part of $SiteName, including meta and chat." (in the context of "Be Civil"). While most sites have no reason for such, writers *might* be a reasonable exception. Even if critique questions are made off-topic, *answers* might wish to use somewhat suggestive language for examples.

I do not think excluding such would have a significant impact on question count ([posting for shock value](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/871/what-should-we-do-with-the-erotica-question#answer-872) seems more likely than real questions), but I think a (further) clarification of policy might be helpful.

(A similar issue would arise with a strict interpretation of the rule concerning expletives. Most people here do not seem inclined to abuse the literal enforcement of rules, and such flags would almost certainly be rejected, but a little extra clarity might be helpful.)

---

Incidentally, the new Code of Conduct is nicely more explicit about expected behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code of conduct is a set of general principles that we expect all users to adhere to, but we recognize that there are some sites where sex is a legitimate part of the scope. If this community decides that erotica is on-topic(which it seems you have), tag all questions accordingly (so users who don't want to see that content can hide it by ignoring the tag), and generally act like mature human beings, you should be fine. If you want to be extra careful, you can use spoiler markup to obscure legitimate but explicit text until a user deliberately mouses over it.

I don't think a specific sub-policy is necessary here yet (given how few questions are in the erotica tag now anyway), but if there's ever an issue with a specific post, bring it here for the community to decide together.

In general, encourage users to flag anything they think is inappropriate, be open to the fact that different people have different levels of comfort with different topics, and err on the side of keeping it as clean as you can. And always, always be open to having discussions about these concerns.